# Typeorm querybuilder group by not working

Tags: typeorm, query-builder

```
const purchaseStates = await this.purchaseState.createQueryBuilder('purchaseState')
        .select('purchaseState.id')
        .select('max(purchaseState.id)')
        .addSelect('purchaseState.purchaseId')
        .where('purchaseState.purchaseId IN (:...purchaseIds)', { purchaseIds })
        .groupBy('purchaseState.purchaseId')
        .getMany()
```

this creates query below

```
select
    "purchaseState"."purchaseId" as "purchaseState_purchaseId",
    "purchaseState"."id" as "purchaseState_id",
    max("purchaseState"."id")
from
    "purchase_state" "purchaseState"
where
    "purchaseState"."purchaseId" in ($1,$2)
group by
    "purchaseState"."purchaseId"
```

Why "purchaseState"."id" as "purchaseState_id" keep showing up?
I don't want to select "purchaseState"."id" but it keep show up in sql

Answer (score 0):

try to use    .getRawMany(); worked for me